# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is not running properly in Lenovo Thinkbook 13s gen 4 ryzen 7 6800u 16gb

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, 22.04, freeze, amd-ryzen

I have recently dual booted Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Windows 11.

When I boot Ubuntu it runs but the typing is lagged when typing with the built-in keyboard and the mouse right click is sometimes stuck until I click again. When I type with external keyboard it works well.

When I open the lid after suspending or closing the lid of the laptop all the icons disappear and mouse pointer becomes a small square box and hangs. I can't even shutdown or reboot the laptop. After doing hard reboot it shows [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fok9k.jpg) on black screen and loops infinitely.

I have to shutdown laptop forcefully. I'm attaching the [log file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aU0ONBzy4WpGi2yiymalYuW-oXkVwWG7?usp=sharing). I am new to Linux so I do not know which log file should I upload so I have uploaded all log files. Please help me to resolve the issue and ask for more information if needed.